# Npgsql code first cannot map JSON datatype with Postgres13

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I have the following simple code-first model

```
    [Key]
    public string LicenceNumber { get; set; }
    public int? Year { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "json")] // problem here.
    public string ModelList { get; set; }
```

Then I tried to create migration file in VS2019 PM console

```
PM> add-migration db1
```

And got error message in PM console, no migration files were created at all.

```
The store type 'json' could not be found in the Npgsql provider manifest
```

I did the search but it didn't help much even developer said [some datatype may not get well support from EF6.](https://github.com/npgsql/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/issues/116)

Here is the environment.

- Entityframework 6.4
- Npgsql 4.1.3
- Postgres 13
- Windows 10, VS2019

Any help/advice would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Npgsql EF6 provider doesn't support JSON - this is indeed related to EF6's type support being problematic.

The EF Core provider does support JSON much better, [see the docs](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco).